# Finding a Capacitor (Condenser) for an ignition coil

Tags: honda, motorcycle, ignition-coil, vintage, capacitor

How would one go about calculating the necessary specs for a capacitor to be paired with an ignition coil?

Comment: [ACDelco D203](https://www.amazon.com/ACDelco-D203-Professional-Ignition-Capacitor/dp/B01LRHCSOA).

Comment: Great question, hope someone has a method for calculating or maybe a chart.

Comment: "spark coil capacitors range from 0.2 microfarad to 0.33 microfarads." .....https://www.smokstak.com/articles/capacitors.html

Comment: Ohm’s law, transformer turns ratios, magnetic field theory and inductances come to mind but you could start here: http://whs.wsd.wednet.edu/faculty/busse/mathhomepage/busseclasses/radiationphysics/lecturenotes/chapter4/chapter4part2.html